# Migrating from cakephp 1.3 to cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I am migrating application code from cake 1.3 to cake 2.4. I am following cakephp [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html).

After following the steps mentioned there I am sill unable to run my code and getting this error:

> Controller class Controller could not be found.

I checked the error log in cakephp and found:

> 2014-06-10 18:37:56 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class Controller  could not be found.
>   Exception Attributes: array (
>     'class' => 'Controller',
>     'plugin' => NULL,
>   )

I am trying to debug it but no results.

Comment: You might also want to look into https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade/

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? And what controllers do you have in the Controller directory?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue today.

You need to have the following 2 lines in your `app/Config/routes.php`

```
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Also, make sure you have updated the .htaccess files in `/`, `app/`, and `app/webroot`.